# How to create a 2D array that values BA and AB are treated as the same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create function that allows me to get all combinations of an array to later generate a list.
 But my problem is that currently my function treat "ab" as  different from "ba". I dont know how to explain it in words but I guess the picture below exemplify what I try to achieve.

[image]

```
function everyCombination($array) {
  $arrayCount      = count($array);
  $maxCombinations = pow($arrayCount, $arrayCount);
  $returnArray     = array();
  $conversionArray = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $conversionArray[base_convert($key, 10, $arrayCount)] = $value;
  }
  for ($i = 0; $i < $maxCombinations; $i++) {
    $combination = base_convert($i, 10, $arrayCount);
    $combination = str_pad($combination, $arrayCount, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $returnArray[] = strtr($combination, $conversionArray);
  }
  return $returnArray;
}

$a = everyCombination(array('a', 'b', 'c','d'));
print_r($a);
```

The desired ouput would be

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
b
bc
bcd
c
cd
d
```

Comment: +1 for a cool graphic.

Comment: Can you provide a sample (for `['a', 'b', 'c']` that will not be too big) of desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is iterate through the array recursively, for each recursion you should only iterate through all the greater elements. Like so:

```
function everyCombination($arr) {
    $combos = array();
    $len = count($arr);
    for( $i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        for( $j=$i+1; $j<=$len; $j++) {
            $combos[] = implode("",array_slice($arr,$i,$j-$i));
        }
    }
    return $combos;
}
```

Example call:

```
everyCombination(['a','b','c','d']);
```

Returns:

```
['a','ab','abc','abcd','b','bc','bcd','c','cd','d']
```

Comment: i also need [`abc`, `abcd`]

Comment: Ah. Your graphic/question didn't make that clear to me. Sorry. I'll edit with an update. Stay tuned! :p

Comment: The `ac`, `ad` and `bd` are not part of the desired output.

Comment: So what you *actually* want is all possible *sequences* of the input. Okay. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're after consecutive results, so a double loop would be a better choice here; recursion requires more control.

```
function combos($array)
{
    if (!$array) {
        return [];
    }

    $n = count($array);
    $r = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
        $prefix = '';
        for ($j = $i; $j < $n; ++$j) {
            $r[] = $prefix . $array[$j];
            $prefix .= $array[$j];
        }
    }

    return $r;
}

print_r(combos([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```